# function doesnt show me pie chart

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

iam struggling with pie chart creation (chart js) and i dont know how to prepare data for chart. i have response in json format, checked via fiddler

```
function OnSuccess_(response) {

    var aData = response.d;
    var data = {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [{
            data: [],
            backgroundColor: []
        }]
    };

    //var ctx = document.getElementById('pele').getContext('2d');

    $.each(aData, function(inx, val) {
        data.labels.push(aData[inx].name);

        alert(aData[inx].turnover);
        alert(aData[inx].color);

        data.datasets[0].data.push(aData[inx].turnover);
        data.datasets[0].backgroundColor.push(aData[inx].color);
    });

    var ctx = $("#pele").get(0).getContext("2d");

    var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: data
    });
}
```

in part $.each(aData, function ....  alert shows me values which i want to display as data(values, and color)bud instead of chart i will retrieve just labels which are -crossed--- out---

can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,  i found problem, why i cant see my Chart. Maybe it will be useful for another members. Data in Database (turnover was daclared as money, i changed it to int .... and it works)